# Increment a number within a formula by 2 each time

Tags: excel, excel-formula, offset

As in this image:

[image: To determine formula to put in the next three set row]

I have the following formula in merged cellset `F229:F231`, which works correctly:

```
=OFFSET('Food Diary'!$A$2,31*(ROWS($F$18:F229)-3),)
```

This pulls data from another worksheet - in this case the value `73.0` is pulled (there are similar formulas in the cell range `H229 to M231`.

Essentially I want the `-3` part at the end of above `OFFSET` formula to increment by two each time I copy and paste the three row set. So in the merged cellset of `F232 - F234` it would be `-5` and in the next one it would be `-7`, then `-9` etc.

It's a bit of a hack but this would result in the correct data being pulled. This is not a work spreadsheet, just a personal log to record my food etc so doesn't have to be ideal.

Comment: You could in `F232 - F234` put `=OFFSET('Food Diary'!$A$2,31*(ROWS($F$18:F232)-3-(COUNTA($F$229:F229)*2)),)` and copy down.

Comment: @jvdV seems to work initially but then when copying down it doesn't. Thanks

Comment: hm, well I can't test on your data, but would `=OFFSET('Food Diary'!$A$2,31*(ROWS($F$18:F232)-1*(3+(COUNTA($F$229:F229)*2))),)` change anything about that? Also try to evaluate the formula to see where it might pick up the wrong value.

Comment: @JvdV I found a way to may it work, in a column to the right of the data, I entered -3 in three of the rows, and then increment those by two for each three row dataset. and then link to this column in the OFFSET formula! A hack, but it does the job!!

Answer (score 3):

Change `-3` to `+2*Row()/3 + c`, where `c` is a modifier to ensure that your first row lines up

For example, if the first row is line 4, and you want the value to be 2:

```
- 2 * Row() / 3 + c
- 2 * 4 / 3 + c
- 8 / 3 + c
- 2.666 + c
c = - 1/3
- 2.666 - 1/3
- 3
- 2 * Row() / 3 - 1/3
```

Then, when you copy it down to Row 7:

```
- 2 * Row() / 3 - 1/3
- 2 * 7 / 3 - 1/3
- 14 / 3 - 1/3
- 4.666 / 3 - 1/3
- 5
```

Comment: Thanks @chronocidal I couldn't get this to work though. Will try again

Comment: Thanks @chronocidal I found a way to may it work, in a column to the right of the data, I entered -3 in three of the rows, and then increment those by two for each three row dataset. and then link to this column in the OFFSET formula! A hack, but it does the job!!

Answer (score 1):

Use one of the following formula for your counter starting at -3 and changing by -2 every three rows.  You can either start using row A1 or you can reference your current cell and make some adjustments to the formula to achieve the same result.

```
=-3-2*(ROUNDUP(ROW(A1)/3,0)-1)

or

=-3-2*(ROUNDDOWN((ROW(G229)-ROW($G$229))/3,0))
```

both will work for generating the number you are looking for

[image: POC]

Your final formula might look like:

```
=OFFSET('Food Diary'!$A$2,31*(ROWS($F$18:F229)+(-3-2*(ROUNDUP(ROW(A1)/3,0)-1))),)
```

Comment: Thanks @Forward Ed ill try this out tomorrow!